# unable to install pyaudio in python 3.9 how to install

Tags: python, module

I'm using VSCode editor I want to install PyAudio but it generating some errors.

I tried to install PyAudio wheels but the compiler said `ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. I'm using python 3.9.

How can I install PyAudio?

Comment: Please show me the ```python --version```and ```python ``` command outputs.

Comment: why are you using cp310 when cp39 is available?

Comment: Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 its python version

Comment: its is the error from the powershell window ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation it looks like you have Python 3.9 on and Windows system.

Please try with the below whl files based on the whether you have 64 bit or 32 bit python installed from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl

or

PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl

Comment: sir if i install tis whl its also generating error ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you choose the wrong version for you computer, have a try with

```
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

as said above